# SQLite ignore null values for min function

Tags: sqlite, null, min

I just noticed that the following query :

`select min(null,0);`

returns `null` whereas I was expecting to get `0`... (Same for `max` function)

In the documentation it says that min() would return null if there is only null values compared. Can somebody explains me how I could ignore null values to get the real value when it's compared to a null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `MIN` when used as an *aggregate* function, and `MIN` used as a *scalar* function.  `MIN` as an aggregate function certainly does ignore `NULL` values (as do most aggregate functions).  This means is that the minimum value of the following column is 3:

```
col
NULL
3
NULL
```

However, SQLite offers `MIN` as a *scalar* function as well.  One approach to ignore `NULL` values here would be to coalesce such null values to the largest possible integer value `9223372036854775807`, e.g.

```
SELECT MIN(COALESCE(col1, 9223372036854775807),
           COALESCE(col2, 9223372036854775807),
           COALESCE(col3, 9223372036854775807)) AS min_value
FROM yourTable;
```

Here if a value be `NULL` then we replace it with a really large value, which then takes it out of consideration for being the smallest number.  If you might have all columns being `NULL`, then you can wrap the above call to `MIN` with a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
select IFNULL(MIN(NULL),0)
select IFNULL(MAX(NULL),0)
```

[IFNULL Document](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d99e4/15)

Comment: This is great ! How exactly the 'IFNULL' function works ?

Comment: What happens if the call to `MIN` has other non null values which are all greater than zero?

Comment: @Arcyno  using  `IFNULL` must have two arguments.
First argument is for checking your field is or isn't `null`.
Seconde argument is the field `null`,what's your except.